# How to bind Button on a UserControl to a Command in the Parent Control?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding

I have a problem of binding my `Button` in a `UserControl` to the `Command` in the parent.

I have a `UserControl` (SearchView) that displays search result data.
That contains a `Menu` in which I want to include a function that resets user settings (font size, sorting, etc.). As there are multiple of such I want to have the Reset Function in its Parent Control (MainView).

MainViewXaml:

```
<UserControl x:class="UI.MainView"
xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Project.Main.UI">
//some stuff here
<ui:SearchView/>
//some stuff here
</UserControl>
```

MainView.xaml.vb:

```
Namespace UI

Public Class MainView

Public ReadOnly Property ResetCommand As New DelegateCommand(AddressOf ResetEinstellungen)

Public Sub ResetEinstellungen()
      //Reset Einstellungen ...
End Sub
```

SearchView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.SearchView"
xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm">
<Grid>
//Table Stuff
</Grid>
<Menu>
    <MenueItem Header="Reset"
               x:Name="ResetButton">
          <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="Click"
                                           Command="{Binding ResetCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl} }">
                    </dxmvvm:EventToCommand>
          </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
     </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I tried some variations already. 
What I want to avoid is to reffer the MainView by its ElementName as I want to potentially use the `UserControl` in other Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `AncestorLevel` to `2` since the default value of `1` will bind to the `SearchView` rather than the `MainView`:

```
Command="{Binding ResetCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=UserControl} }
```

Answer (score 2):

I put an experiment together.

This works for me:

```
   <MenuItem Header="Reset"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.ResetCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl} }"/>
```

Note:

DataContext.CommandName

You can use command on the menuitem rather than eventtocommand.

Comment: So I was more or less right already, but I still can't get it to execute my methode when I click it, which is strange to me.
The MainView is in a DialogWindow which is part of a  ContainerControlledLifetimeManager but is beside that pretty much barebone, so I am really just guessing at this point what my problem is. I also don't get anything from the Debugger why it hasn't binded or why it isn't executing.